# Upgrading iOS SDK

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk, xcode4

Hey, sorry for the dumb question, but how can I upgrade iOS SDK to the newest version without downloading the xcode 4 again(4,3gb)? Thanks!

Comment: Let someone else downloading it? =/

Comment: Xcode actually isn't that big.  The SDK is what takes up most of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. The only way to get the newest SDK is to download the newest XCode 4 build.